# PHP if statements with multiple values

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a shorter way of writing this?

```
<? 
if($_GET['id']==1 ||
$_GET['id']==3 ||
$_GET['id']==4 || 
$_GET['id']==5)
{echo 'does it really have to be this explicit?'};
?>
```

Something like this perhaps?

```
<?
if($_GET['id']==1 || 3 || 4 || 5){echo 'this is much shorter'};
?>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just try with:

```
if ( in_array($_GET['id'], array(1, 3, 4, 5)) ) {}
```

Comment: This is the shortest way I know. Additionally it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not shorter but more readable.  Try the in_array() function:

```
if (in_array($_GET['id'], array(1, 3, 4, 5)))
{
  echo "What about this?";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps switch may help

```
switch($_GET['id']) {
    case 1: 
    case 3: 
    case 4: 
    case 5:
        echo 'Slect maybe :P';
        break;
}
```

Comment: I don't know a function `select()` - can you point me to the manual on php.net? And who votes that up????

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression like below:

```
preg_match(['1-4']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array:

```
$values = array(1,3,4,5);
```

Get your variable

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now use PHP in_array();

```
if(in_array($id, $values)){
//do something
}
```

Read about [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php%E2%80%8E)